# startActivity(i) bringing wrong activity to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity X that receives the launcher intent and call Y. Y registers a broadcast receiver and calls `moveTaskToBack(true)`. The receiver performs `startActivity(Y)` (to bring it back to front) but it brings X to top when it was supposed to bring Y. 
The Activity Y is like this in the `manifest.xml`

```html
<activity
          android:name=".Y"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_input_password"
          android:launchMode="singleInstance">

</activity
```

```html
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("[YActivity]", "MyReceiver");

            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
                Log.i("[YActivity]", "Screen ON");
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Y.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
//                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                Log.i("[YActivity]", "Screen OFF");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure when invoking `startActivity(Y)`, app does not crash ?

Comment: post some code please

Comment: @JibranKhan Yes, I'm sure.